# Ignoring slug capitalization on rewrite rule for custom post type archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, custom-post-type-archives

I'm declaring a custom post type 'games' with a rewrite rule:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Games','with_front' => false),
```

So the resulting url for the games archive is `<mysite>.com/Games` - This works fine.

With a Game entry titled "Example", visiting `<mysite>.com/games/Example` it automatically redirects to `<mysite>.com/Games/Example` no problem. This is what I want.

---

However when visiting the archive of the `Games` type, it will not redirect if I change the capitalization:

- With the slug set to `Games` visiting `<mysite>.com/Games` works but visiting `<mysite>.com/games` will redirect to a blog post or page with 'games' in its url.
- With the slug set to `games` visiting `<mysite>.com/games` works but visiting `<mysite>.com/Games` will redirect to a blog post or page with 'games' in its url.

**Notes**:

- Yes, I flush my permalink settings after changing the rewrite rules. Since the url works for the non-archive pages this is not the issue.
- I use the custom `Month and name` permalink setting.
- I do have `archive-games.php` defined and working in my theme directory.

---

Is there a way of ensuring that any case variation of 'games' links to the archive, and not some random blog post?

In other words, is it possible to tell wordpress to ignore the capitalization and always redirect to `<mysite>.com/Games` even if the user enters `<mysite>.com/gAMeS`?

I just want it to be convenient for users that happen to type the url in manually and forget to capitalize it.

I could change the slug to lower case 'games' by default, but then

1. It doesn't look as nice
2. Again, if a user types "Games" with caps, They are linked to a seemingly random page.

Comment: Did you flush rewrite rules after adding this CPT?

Comment: Yes, after changing the slug I always flush the rewrite rules. The point is that the rules only work for one case or the other. I can't have both `<mysite>.com/Games` and `<mysite>.com/games` working simultaneously, which is what I want. Whichever one I choose, the other url will then link to the first blog post it finds that contains "games".

Comment: I checked source code of WP and it looks like WP is case-sensitive in this scope. You can of course add custom rewrites (rewrite Games to games) but it isn't very neat solution :(

Comment: Hmm, Could you elaborate? Apart from the rewrite rule in the post type declaration I don't know much about rewriting with Wordpress. Would this be in .htaccess?

Comment: Most of the WP rewrite rules are stored in database. You can add this Games->games rule in .htaccess though (it will be fastest, cleanest and easiest solution).